Solidity code not highlighted properly with minted and the GitHub Dark style
I am trying to add some highlighted Solidity code snippets to a LaTeX document. I am using the minted package to leverage the advanced highlighting capabilities of pygments.
The issue I am facing is that some of the Solidity tokens are not properly highlighted:

The highlighting for other more popular languages such as Java works fine:

Here is my TeX code:
\documentclass[
]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}
\definecolor{github_dark_bg}{HTML}{0D1117}

\setminted[solidity]{
    autogobble=true,
    frame=lines,
    framesep=2mm,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    breaklines=true,
    bgcolor=github_dark_bg
}

\usemintedstyle{github-dark}

\begin{document}

\section{OZ's ERC165 implementation:}

\begin{minted}[autogobble]{solidity}
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    // OpenZeppelin Contracts (last updated v5.0.0) (utils/introspection/ERC165.sol)
    
    pragma solidity ^0.8.20;
    
    import {IERC165} from "./IERC165.sol";
    
    /**
     * @dev Implementation of the {IERC165} interface.
     *
     * Contracts that want to implement ERC-165 should inherit from this contract and override {supportsInterface} to check
     * for the additional interface id that will be supported. For example:
     *
     * ```solidity
     * function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override returns (bool) {
     *     return interfaceId == type(MyInterface).interfaceId || super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
     * }
     * ```
     */
    abstract contract ERC165 is IERC165 {
        /**
         * @dev See {IERC165-supportsInterface}.
         */
        function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual returns (bool) {
            return interfaceId == type(IERC165).interfaceId;
        }
    }
\end{minted}

\end{document}

I am using pdflatex for the PDF generation:
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error -shell-escape solidity.tex

Is that a misconfiguration in my TeX code or an issue with the Solidity lexer in pygments? Any idea how I can fix that?

Welcome to TeX.SE!

The Github dark style does not define a color for plain text, which is therefore printed in the default black font. Putting the code into https://pygments.org/demo/ with the Solidity lexer and selecting Tokens as Formatter shows that there are many tokens with class Text that are therefore invisible with a black background.
As a solution you can set the format color in minted using the key formatcom, which applies to anything that gets the default color. This includes the frame, if you don't want that you can set that to black again with the key rulecolor.
Code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}
\definecolor{github_dark_bg}{HTML}{0D1117}

\setminted[solidity]{
    autogobble=true,
    frame=lines,
    framesep=2mm,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    breaklines=true,
    bgcolor=github_dark_bg,
    formatcom=\color{white},
    rulecolor=black,
}

\usemintedstyle{github-dark}

\begin{document}

\section{OZ's ERC165 implementation:}
\begin{minted}[autogobble]{solidity}
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    // OpenZeppelin Contracts (last updated v5.0.0) (utils/introspection/ERC165.sol)
    
    pragma solidity ^0.8.20;
    
    import {IERC165} from "./IERC165.sol";
    
    /**
     * @dev Implementation of the {IERC165} interface.
     *
     * Contracts that want to implement ERC-165 should inherit from this contract and override {supportsInterface} to check
     * for the additional interface id that will be supported. For example:
     *
     * ```solidity
     * function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override returns (bool) {
     *     return interfaceId == type(MyInterface).interfaceId || super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
     * }
     * ```
     */
    abstract contract ERC165 is IERC165 {
        /**
         * @dev See {IERC165-supportsInterface}.
         */
        function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual returns (bool) {
            return interfaceId == type(IERC165).interfaceId;
        }
    }
\end{minted}

\end{document}

Result:


Thank you so much! That worked like a charm.
